# exec(); or shell_exec(); performance issue

Tags: php, linux, bash, command

I'm trying to execute by php exec(); a bash file which runs a process based on curl looping script. The problem is I've tried these methods:

```
exec();
shell_exec();
sudo -S  nice -n -20
sudo -i
> /dev/null 2>/dev/null & (achro)
```

and started process by PHP  exec(); are slow, response from curl is milliseconds slower than if I run it manually on SSH console directly as a command.

I have it this way right now:

start.php run this:

```
echo shell_exec('echo "password" | sudo -S  nice -n -20 ./new.sh > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

new.sh run this

```
sudo -i /home/scripts/source/do.bat > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

and do.bat run this

```
cd /home/scripts/a/2
echo "" > output.txt
./check.bat & echo $! > check.pid
cd /home/scripts/a/6
echo "" > output.txt
./check.bat & echo $! > check.pid
```

When I execute directly ./do.bat at console, script runs pretty fast, curl responses are as I need and everything goes fine, output.txt is written with a decent output speed.

But when I try to run it with PHP exec(); curl responses are slow down, and does not work as I need. Also you will ask why I run new.sh with start.php instead runs directly do.bat with start.php? Because if I do it, I get an output response very weird with an -e wrote on text.

Somebody can help me to make it run at same speed as if I run manually on console as command?

Comment: why are you doing in bash what you could do in php?

Comment: Its just to start two automated processes which makes requests with curl in linux. But I just need to know how to start them fast as if I do it manually

Comment: php has curl, mixing languages will always make this harder